# Stored procedure call in osb 12c

Tags: oracle12c, osb

I am getting error while calling stored procedure in service call out of pipeline in osb 12 c. 
PLS-00653: Aggregate/table functions are not allowed in PL/SQL scope. If somebody's faced it before or could help here?

Answer (score 0):

I used fn:bea-executeSql function and got to call the procedure successfully. It is very simple also as there is no need of creating dB adapter.